# Contact not created when running New-MailContact cmdlet from C# code

Tags: c#, powershell, active-directory, powershell-cmdlet

I have an application which (among other things) needs to call the New-MailContact cmdlet and create contacts in Active Directory.  I have followed a handful of tech articles to get as far as I have, but it is still not working.

I have verified my service account being used has the proper authentication based on [this TechNet page](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb124519%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx).  I am able to find and invoke the cmdlet from powershell, and I recieve no errors.

However, after running I inspect my OU and my contact was not created.  I found [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/555190) KB article which I think may be suspect, but since the cmdlet doesn't return any errors after the invoke, I can't be sure that this will solve my problem.

Here is a snippet of what I am doing:

```
    public bool CreateMailContactObject(ADExchangeContact adExchangeContacts)
    {
        Collection<PSObject> results;
        Pipeline pipeLine = null;

        try
        {
            var runspaceConfiguration = RunspaceConfiguration.Create();
            PSSnapInException snapInException;
            var snapInInfo = runspaceConfiguration.AddPSSnapIn("Microsoft.Exchange.Management.PowerShell.Admin", out snapInException);

            using (var runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(runspaceConfiguration))
            {
                var newMailBoxContact = new Command("New-MailContact");
                newMailBoxContact.Parameters.Add("Name", adExchangeContacts.DisplayName);
                newMailBoxContact.Parameters.Add("ExternalEmailAddress", adExchangeContacts.ExternalEmailAddress);
                newMailBoxContact.Parameters.Add("OrganizationalUnit", adExchangeContacts.OrganizationalUnit);
                newMailBoxContact.Parameters.Add("Alias", adExchangeContacts.Alias);

                runspace.Open();

                pipeLine = runspace.CreatePipeline();
                pipeLine.Commands.Add(newMailBoxContact);

                results = pipeLine.Invoke();

                _log.DebugFormat("results.Count = {0}", results.Count);
                results.ForEach(x => x.Properties.ForEach(y => _log.DebugFormat("{0}: {1}", y.Name, y.Value)));

                pipeLine.Stop();
                runspace.Close();
            }

            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // Add log statement
            _log.ErrorFormat("Creation of Mail Contact in AD Failed. Error: {0}", ex);
            return false;
        }            
    }
```

I do not get any exceptions, and my result list is empty from the Pipeline invoke.  Is there something I am missing?  If the cmdlet fails due to permissions when creating the contact in AD, wouldn't I expect to recieve some sort of error in the result set from `pipeLine.Invoke()` ??

I am new with running Powershell, so if there is another issue (beyond the KB article) that could be at hand, please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    if (pipeline.Error != null && pipeline.Error.Count > 0)
                {
                    StringBuilder pipelineError = new StringBuilder();
                    pipelineError.AppendFormat("Error calling Add-MailboxPermission.");
                    foreach (object item in thisPipeline.Error.ReadToEnd())
                    {
                        pipelineError.AppendFormat("{0}\n", item.ToString());
                    }

                    ErrorText = ErrorText + "Error: " + pipelineError.ToString() + Environment.NewLine;
                }
```

Please Put this code after **pipeline.Invoke()** and check if there is any error in there

**Update:**
I think this is erro with giving right permission to user,some solutions for this:

http://boardreader.com/thread/Microsoft_Exchange_2010_wont_allow_new_M_1w69j__37ad9f8a-cdcf-4d26-9384-00ad1a3d0f91.html
http://blogs.technet.com/b/richardroddy/archive/2010/07/12/exchange-2010-and-the-exchange-trusted-subsystem.aspx

Comment: Thank you.  I am marking your answer as correct.  It didn't solve my problem, but you educated me on how to get more details out of my call.  The results are: `2012-05-08 15:58:38,227 [DEBUG] (MyProject.Core.Services.ADService) Error: Error calling New-MailContact.Active Directory operation failed on MY-SERVER.Domain.com. This error is not retriable. Additional information: Access is denied.
Active directory response: 00000005: SecErr: DSID-031521D0, problem 4003 (INSUFF_ACCESS_RIGHTS), data 0`  Looks like the KB article is my culprit.

Comment: Per your update, we are using Exchange 2007, so I think it's my service account rights as opposed to the ETS.  Thank you again!